# How to get a subset of entries in a treemap?

Tags: java, xpages

I have a

TreeMap map = new TreeMap();

to store values from documents in a view based on a selection criteria. map stores the creation date as the key and the document values as an object.

Within the object, I have a "form" field. documents can have different forms ( memo, notice, fax etc )

I have a method to return allEntries. That is ok and works as expected.

I now want to make a selection on the form field to return only a subset of the documents in the map.

Can someone point me into the right direction how to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the you want to select on something which is not the key of the map, you have to iterate over all the items.

If you can use external libraries, you could use [`Collections2.filter()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) from google's [guava libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). I.E.

```
TreeMap<Date, Document> map = ...;
final String formValue = "notice";
Collection<Document> result = Collections2.filter(map.values(), new Predicate<Document>() {
    public boolean apply(Document input) {
        return formValue .equals(input.getForm());
    }
}
```

Comment: On the same lines, you could also try the Commons Collections Predicates http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/Predicate.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 maps to store the data.

One simple Hashmap would suffice to store the id corresponding to memo-notice etc and as a value a Treemap containing all the corresponing data in your current format.

Answer (score 0):

You can 
1) go through all values and put those matching criteria into new collection
2) store it other collections (either separate variables or Map> (or something like that, consider using set instead of List)

1) slower retrieval, 2) slower remove, more memory consumed

Answer (score 0):

guava libraries worked, but is a bit of an overkill. So I ended up with the following

```
TreeMap<String, Object> mapFiltered = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
LinkedList<CommunicationDocumentEntry> map = new LinkedList<CommunicationDocumentEntry>();

    public Collection<Object> getAllEntries(String frm, boolean order) {
    this.mapFiltered.clear();

    Iterator<CommunicationDocumentEntry> itr = this.map.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        CommunicationDocumentEntry entry = itr.next();
        if (EMPTY_STRING.equals(frm) || frm == null) {
            this.mapFiltered.put(entry.getDateCreated(), entry.getEntry());
        } else {
            if (entry.getForm().toUpperCase().equals(frm.toUpperCase())) {
                this.mapFiltered.put(entry.getDateCreated(), entry.getEntry());
            }
        }
    }

    if (order) {
        return this.mapFiltered.descendingMap().values();
    } else {
        return this.mapFiltered.values();
    }
}
```

Certainly not perfect, but works for me ...